# Calculate power of a multi-way ANOVA in R

Tags: r

I'm aware of the pwr.anova.test function to calculate the power of a one-way ANOVA in R however, I can't find anything on how to calculate the power for a multi-way ANOVA?

Answer (score 0):

So I may have found a solution but I'm not entirely sure.

```
# Calculating power for a multi - way ANOVA
# https://rdrr.io/cran/easypower/man/n.multiway.html 
#install.packages("easypower")
library(easypower)

#Calculating the eta_squared for the variables in my ANCOVA model

eta_squared(ancova, type = 2, anova = T)

# Defining the treatments and interaction
main.eff.1 <- list(name = "Sex", levels = 2, eta.sq =  8.63e-03)
main.eff.2 <- list(name = "PCW", levels = 8, eta.sq = 0.06)
main.eff.3 <- list(name = "Genotype", levels = 3, eta.sq = 4.17e-03)
main.eff.4 <- list(name = "ReadLength", levels = 3, eta.sq = 0.06)
# not sure about this one so commented out main.eff.5 <- list(name = "RIN", levels = 3, eta.sq = 0.06)
# Running n.multiway

n.multiway(iv1 = main.eff.1, iv2 = main.eff.2, iv3 = main.eff.3, iv4 = main.eff.4,
           interaction.eta2 = "small", sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, result = "highest")
```

The output is

"The following is the largest recommended total sample size.

Desired power: 0.80
Significance level: 0.05
Effect size used in calculations: Cohen's f-squared
Cutoffs: small = 0.01, med = 0.06, large = 0.14

Treatment: PCW*Genotype*ReadLength
Effect Size: small
Total N: 2501
n per cell: 18"

Which I think means I would need a sample size of 2501.